# How to build Bitcoin binaries for Windows on Ubuntu using cross-compile

Tags: bitcoin-core, windows, compiling, bitcoin-qt-setup

I am trying to build Bitcoin 0.13 for Windows. I've always used [this](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=149479.0) guide for building previous versions. Now seems that developers have changed their mind regarding Windows, and the new way seems cross-compile from Ubuntu. I have followed step by step [the new instructions](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/0.13/doc/build-windows.md), but I haven't been able to get it built. Seems that instructions are either not correct or not up to date. Here is what I've found so far:

- zconf.h file not found, solved manually copying it from `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu` to `projectdir/depends/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include`
- [**unsolved**]`warning: undefined symbols not allowed in x86_64-w64-mingw32 shared libraries; building static only` while compiling secp256k1 lib
- [**unsolved**] I tried to `configure` and `make` secp256k1 manually before running the "main" make for solving previous issue, but then I get this error: `/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: attempted static link of dynamic object secp256k1/.libs/libsecp256k1.so`

I stuck here, any help is appreciated. Also, I could also accept to build on Windows (like before) if necessary, as long as it works. Thanks.

Comment: Bitcoin Core releases binaries have been cross-compiled since forever (0.3.x era), though builds on Windows have been and still are possible.

Comment: Many thanks for this info. So how do I solve the above errors?

Comment: The second error, "warning: undefined symbols" may be the end of line character in the code. By the way, what is reason behind in Windows OS? The processing speed would be slower...

Answer (score 0):

By using the pull request and instructions at https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/11526 you can build Bitcoin Core, except the two Qt dependent projects, with Visual Studio (or msbuild tools) on Windows.